# Didiving axis by months for XY scatter chart in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-time

I have the data plotted on a yearly basis, which requires the division between full months.
Unfortunately, it seems like this option is not possible in the XY scatter chart, because the `Axis type` option is missing.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/missing-axis-type-option/1ac196d0-d68e-4a25-9504-bf0d1f5ba4b6

If the axis type for the following chart would be available, I could be able to set the month names between the grids as shown in the thread here:

https://www.get-digital-help.com/how-to-position-month-and-year-between-chart-tick-marks/

But it looks like the only one option is like shown here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51477752/how-can-i-plot-time-in-the-x-axis-of-a-scatter-plot-in-excel

which in my case looks almost correct, when playing more with major units.

A year has 365 days, I should divide my chart by something like 30.2 - 30.4, then my chart has the biggest sense. Regrettably, I still have discrepancies between months. I would like to have every month starting from the first day, 1.01, 1.02, 1.03, and so on. I have it just for January, August - December. Other months are pointed at the last or second day, as you can see below:
[image]

Is it a chance for dividing the major units by equal months across the year for this type of chart?